# GPS Location is being saved automatically without approval

Tags: android-intent, navigation, gps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

Okay my problem is this:

I have two Activities, A and B.

In Activity A I have a webview which presents a google map with coordinates that are taken from a SharedPreferences DB file. if the DB file is empty then the google map query gets default values.

Now when I go to Activity B, the GPS Location starts working and it lets me decide if I want to save my current location (I can either click on the "save" button which saves the current location to the DB file or just click on the "get back without saving" button which takes me back to Activity A without saving the location.

The thing is, when I click on the "get back without saving" the location in Activity A changes!! it has been updated even though I didn't click on the "save" button! 
how can this be?

Does anybody have a clue? please help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that onStop() method caused this issue.
onStop() worked everytime I switched between A and B Activites and saved the last location.

The whole purpose of implementing onStop() was just in case the app crashes and not when switching between Activities.

Does anybody have an idea on how to set it correctly?